# Bootstrap-Sass not working with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-sass

i have recently tried using boostrap-sass following the steps from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#sass - however there seemes to be an error when i try viewing my webpage on localhost. Here is the error message when i run rails server
**NOTE: I have added gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0' to the gem file, as well as added @import 'bootstrap' to my styles.css.scss document**

```
 Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-26 16:18:16 -0500
   Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
     Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (7.0ms)
   WARN: tilt autoloading 'sass' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'sass'
   suggested.
   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 951ms

   ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: boostrap.
   Load paths:
     c:/RailsInstaller/DevKit/omrails/app/assets/images
     c:/RailsInstaller/DevKit/omrails/app/assets/javascripts
     c:/RailsInstaller/DevKit/omrails/app/assets/stylesheets
     c:/RailsInstaller/DevKit/omrails/vendor/assets/javascripts
     c:/RailsInstaller/DevKit/omrails/vendor/assets/stylesheets
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/turbolinks-2.2.0/lib/asse
   ts/javascripts
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.4/vendor
   /assets/javascripts
     (in c:/RailsInstaller/DevKit/omrails/app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css.scss:1)
   ):
       2:  <html>
       3:  <head>
       4:  <title>Omrails</title>
       5:  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks
   -track" => true %>
       6:  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => tru
   e %>
       7:  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
       8:  </head>
     app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css.scss:1
     app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_ht
   ml_erb___872362987_32078088'


     Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2
   /lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (3.0ms)
     Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2
   /lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0
   ms)
     Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2
   /lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within resc
   ues/layout (33.0ms)
   [2014-01-26 16:18:18] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was a
   borted by the software in your host machine.
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `
   eof?'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `
   run'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `blo
   ck in start_thread'
```

Comment: @aceofspades i already had gem 'bootstrap' added to my gemfile, as specified in the steps that the github link above provides

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'` to your Gemfile.